# Проблема с отправкой

Tags: html, php, javascript

На странице есть 4 `<form>`:

- 1 `form` - добавляет в БД инфу о товаре.(поля `name`, `cena`, `opt_cena`, `postavshik<select>` ...)
- 2 `form` - добавляет "поставщика товара"(поля `name`, `phone`, `email`)
- 3 `form` - добавляет "категории товаров"(поля `name`, `info`)
- 4 `form` - добавляет "место хранения товара" (поля `sklad`, `info`)

Занося данные в 1 форму пользователь может из `<select>` выбирать "поставщика товара", и если его нет в списке то можно ниже в `form2` добавить "поставщика товара" и потом выбрать его из списка `<select>` но ... при нажатии кнопки "Добавить поставщика" все `form` обновляются и данные которые пользователь ввел до выбора "поставщика" пропадают =)

ВОПРОС: как можно это "разрулить"? т.е. както при нажатии на `submit` ("добавить поставщика") запомнить заполненные поля и после добавления в `<select>` нового "поставщика" заполнить их обратно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

сделать у формы, которая добавляет поставщиков, preventDefault js-ом, и ajax-запросом поставщика инсёртить в БД и подсовывать в список.

Comment: а как то на PHP это нельзя зделать? т.е. те данные которые были введены до добавления поставщика выдернуть из form1? =)

Comment: Так формы-то разные, когда отправляете из одной формы - данные другой в PHP не придут.

Здесь либо все в одну форму пихать и делать 4 сабмита. По нажатому сабмиту обрабатывать данные и возвращать полученные значения (как раз то, что вы хотите)

Либо как сказали - через AJAX все делать.

Comment: Заключил в form0 те 4 формы. При нажатии на submit"Добавить поставщика" во 2 форме, ничего не происходит =(
добавил еще один submit к form0, $_POST посылает все элементы формы =) т.е. submit тех 4 форм не срабатывают =(

Comment: Все разобрался, была ошибка.ю тэг не закрыл =) спс большое.

Answer (score 0):

используйте Jquery для облегчения жизни и во вторую форму встевте hidden поля
например чтото вроде

```
<script>
function addPostavchik() {
$("#form1ProductName").val($("#productName").val());
$("#form2").submit();    
}
</script>

<form id="form1" ..... >
<input name="productName" id="productName" type="text">
...... тут остальные поля    
</form>

<form id="form2" action="script.php">
<input type="hidden" id="form1ProductName" name="form1ProductName">
<input type="text" name="postavchik">
<input type="button" onclick="addPostavchik();" value="Добавить">
</form>
```

по аналогии добавьте значения из первой формы во вторую и в скрипт присвоения ихже перед отправкой, тогда на обработчик формы вы сможете передавать также значения из первой формы - не обьединяя все в одну форму, ну а далее из обработчика после добавления поставщика в момент возвращения на страницу с формами этиже данные передавайте на эту страницу, ну а на странице уже чтото вроде

```
<input type="text" name="productName" id="productName" value="<? echo (!empty($_GET['productName'])) ? htmlspecialchars($_GET['productName']) : '';?>">
```

или если не хотите прописывать hidden поля вручную, вот скриптик который сделает это автоматом, ну также функция addPostavchik

```
function addPostavchik() {
$("#form1 input").each(function(){
var str = '<input type="hidden" name="form1-'+$(this).attr("name")+'" value="'+$(this).val()+'">';
$('#form2').append(str);
});
$('#form2').submit();
}
```

эта функция создаст в форме 2, все поля из формы 1 с именем "form1-<оригинальное имя>" и отправит все эти данные, ну а дальше также отправлять их на форму с обработчика

Comment: <?php
print_r($_POST);
$p = $_POST;
echo "<br> post от кнопки ".$_POST["send"];
if ($_POST["clear"]) {unset($p);}
?>
<form name="tovar" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<label>Товар</label>
<input name="p1" type="text" value="<?php echo $p["p1"] ?>">
<input name="send" type="submit" value="Send P1"><br>

<label>Поставщик</label>
<input name="p2" type="text" value="<?php echo $p["p2"] ?>">
<input name="send" type="submit" value="Send P2"><br>

<input name="clear" type="submit" value="Очистить"><input name="send" type="submit" value="Send All">
</form>

СПС решил на мой взгляд проще